# Proving that $\ln r$ is harmonic as a function 0f $z=(x,y)$ where $r$ is the norm of $z-\zeta$ for $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus

Let $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $r= \left|z- \zeta \right|$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $\ln r$ is harmonic as a function of $z=(x,y)$ in the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus \big\{ \zeta \big\}$.

Work so far:

Let $\zeta = (x^\prime, y^\prime)$. Then

$\begin{align} \ln r = \ln \left|z - \zeta \right| &=\ln \left|(x-x^\prime,y-y^\prime) \right| \\&= \ln \sqrt{(x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y^\prime)^2} \\&= (\star) \hspace{1mm} \frac{1}{2} \ln ((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y^\prime)^2) \end{align}$.

For a function $u(x,y)$, the Laplacian $\Delta u(x,y)$ is defined as $\Delta u(x,y) = u_{xx}+u_{yy}$. The Laplacian in polar coordinates is $\Delta u (r, \theta) = u_{rr}+ \frac{1}{r} u_r + \frac{1}{r^2} u_{\theta \theta}$. We need to show that $\Delta u = 0$.

This is where I get stuck. I'm having trouble converting $(\star)$ to polar coordinates so that I can take the partials $u_{rr}$, $u_r$ and $u_{\theta \theta}$. Do I just set $(x,y)=(rcos \theta, r sin \theta)$ and $(x^\prime,y^\prime)=(r^\prime cos \theta^\prime, r^\prime sin \theta^\prime)$ and then take the partial derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ separately? Do I just ignore the variables $(x^\prime,y^\prime)$? Any help appreciated!

Edit: I tried taking the partials $u_x$, $u_y$, $u_{xx}$, $u_{yy}$ in rectangular coordinates for $$u(x,y)= \frac{1}{2} \ln ((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y^\prime)^2):$$

$u_x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2} \cdot 2(x-x^\prime)=\frac{x-x^\prime}{(x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2}$

$u_y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2} \cdot 2(y-y^\prime)=\frac{y-y^\prime}{(x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2}$

$u_{xx}= \frac{((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2)-(x-x^\prime) \cdot 2(x-x^\prime)}{((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2)^2}$

$u_{yy}= \frac{((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2)-(y-y^\prime) \cdot 2(y-y^\prime)}{((x-x^\prime)^2+(y-y)^2)^2}$

but it doesn't seem like $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$. What am I doing wrong? I apologize if this seems simple, I haven't taken a calculus course in about four years.

Comment: Your derivatives look fine. Observe that you can write the numerator of $u_{xx}$ as $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2-2(x-x')^2=(y-y')^2-(x-x')^2$.

Comment: Similarly for $u_{yy}$, with opposite signs.

Comment: Since the denominators are the same, you can just add the numerators to get $0$.

Comment: @spinoza Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, you did all the hard work yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you feel the need for polar coordinates?

As you said, we need the Laplacian  $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, where in our case
$$
u(x,y)=\ln|(x,y)-(x',y')|.
$$
We treat $(x',y')$ as an arbitrary constant in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now just differentitae $u$ twice with respect to $x$ and twice with respect to $y$ and take the sum $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$.

Comment: I tried taking the partials in regular coordinates and had trouble. I know the partial derivatives are not that hard to compute, but It's been awhile since I've taken a calculus class. Could you help me figure out where I went wrong in my computations? I tried properly applying the chain rule and quotient rule to obtain $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ but I think I may have made a mistake in my calculation